# Do I store openid AND oauth tokens in same table or separate tables?

Tags: database, database-design, oauth, openid

For example:

```
openid
------
id
user_id
provider
url

oauth
-----
id
user_id
provider
token
secret
```

OR:

```
identities
----------
id
user_id
provider
token (token here is oauth token or openid_url)
secret (nullable)
```

The bottom one bothers me even though it's easier because secret is dependent upon token

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two protocols are completely different, have different security properties, and should not be combined.